# How to compare data from 2 different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare data from 2 pandas dataframes, in Python. I got 1 column that is a common one in both of them, but they got different names. In the first one the name of the column is "File" and in the second one, 'Código da transação'. Anyway, I created this function, to compare data, but I got ERROR in those lines... Why is that happening?

```
def checar_valor(a,b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if  b.isin([a['File'][i]]): #ERROR
            print("O valor %s está presente nos dois dataframes" % a['File'][i])
        else:
            print("O valor %s está presente apenas no dataframe %s" % (a['File'][i], "a"))

for q in range(len(b)):
    if a.isin([b['Código da transação'][q]]): #ERROR
        print("O valor %s está presente nos dois dataframes" % b['Código da transação'][q])
    else:
        print("O valor %s está presente apenas no dataframe %s" % (b['Código da transação'][q], "b"))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nick/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/Extranet/testezin.py", line 75, in <module>
    checar_valor(rs, ga)
  File "C:/Users/nick/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/Extranet/testezin.py", line 64, in checar_valor
    if  b.isin([a['File'][i]]): #ERRO
  File "C:\Users\nick\PycharmProjects\WebCrawler\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1576, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: What do you mean with common? Identical content? Similar values?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What return you expect? TRUE/FALSE? For the entire dataframe or each row?

Comment: @Pedro : what exactly do you want to achieve? find the difference between both df w.r.t the common column?

Comment: The return should be "X is in dataset A and is not in dataset B" "Y is in dataset B and is not in dataset A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.where` you can get a DataFrame containing the values that are in both DataFrames and at the same position

```
df1.where(df1.values==df2.values)
```

> Edit : following your comment, this should work :

```
A = pd.DataFrame([4,2,3], columns = ['Number'])
B = pd.DataFrame([2,5,6], columns = ['Number'])

a = set(A['Number'])
b = set(B['Number'])

my_set = set(a | b) #put every value in a set, so that you don't check each column twice

for i in my_set:
    if i in A['Number'].values:
        if i in B['Number'].values:
            print(str(i) + ' is in both DataFrames')
        else :
            print(str(i) + ' is in A but not in B')
    else: #if the value is not in A, it is obviously in B
        print(str(i) + ' is in B but not in A')
```

Output:

```
2 is in both DataFrames 
3 is in A but not in B 
4 is in A but not in B
5 is in B but not in A 
6 is in B but not in A
```

Comment: I got it, but my objective is to return the values that contains in one of the datasets and don't contain in the other... example:

a = (1,2,3)
b = (2,3,6)

the output should be: "1 is in a and is not in b and 6 is in b and is not in a"

Comment: Also... I got one more issue... I am trying to analysis these two dataframes and generate a csv archive. I already did it, but I created one column named "Not found" which contains the incompatibilities you helped me out finding! The problem is that I need to get the index of the row that contains the incompatibility, to update the value to "this is not in A" or "this is not in B". How to I get the index value of a known value?

Comment: If each value is unique and you want to get the index of the row where there is the X value, you can use loc like this : A.loc[A['Number'] == X].index[0]